# display elements horizontally (in one line) in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my `div`:

```
 <div class="PictureContent1" style="display:inline-block" value="1"> </div>
```

This is the content:

[image]

```
for(var i = 0; i<ui.item.productpictureurl.length; i++){
                        $('div.PictureContent1').append("<img width='100px' height='100px' src='" + ui.item.productpictureurl[i] + "' />");
                        var radioBtn = '<input type="radio" name="'+ui.item.label+'" data-urlId="'+ui.item.productpictureurl[i]+'" />';
                        $('div.PictureContent1').append(radioBtn);                                  
                    }
```

I need to display `<img>` and `radiobuttons` inside this div in one line. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Add `float: left` to them in the `style` attribute.

Comment: Please share your rendered HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to your HTML
`.PictureContent1 img{ float:left}` or Change code to

```
    for(var i = 0; i<ui.item.productpictureurl.length; i++){
$('div.PictureContent1').append("<div style='float:left'>");
                            $('div.PictureContent1').append("<img width='100px' height='100px' src='" + ui.item.productpictureurl[i] + "' />");
                            var radioBtn = '<input type="radio" name="'+ui.item.label+'" data-urlId="'+ui.item.productpictureurl[i]+'" />';
                            $('div.PictureContent1').append(radioBtn); 
$('div.PictureContent1').append("</div>");                                 
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `float: left` to them, to fix your problem, but then another problem will arise because the floats will not be cleared, so the code that comes after those images will look buggy.

Look into [clearing floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html).